# duplicate properties created for class with attributes "DataContract" and "Serializable"

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-client

I have a class with 2 attributes on it, "DataContract" and "Serializable". This class is being used in a service. This service is being consumed by a project. I have added the reference of the service in the project by using the "add service reference" functionality of VS (Right Click on references -- Add -- Service Reference). Whenever I add the reference of the service, duplicate properties of the class is created in the Reference.cs file of the service reference, 1 with "DataMember" attribute and other with "Serializable" attribute. This is causing a build error. If I do not put the Serializable attribute, the service reference works fine with just 1 set of properties of the class with "DataMember" attribute.

Any idea why is this happening and what can we do to avoid this? Please note that both the attributes are required for the class i.e. I cannot remove any of the attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain why you need both the attributes?

`DataContractSerializer` works fine with `Serializable` attribute.

But, for `BinaryFormattor` to work, you need `Serializable` attribute.

Find a way to get rid of `DataContract` attribute.

--EDIT--

`WCF` uses `DataContractSerializer` by default to serialize/deserialize objects over channels. According to `MSDN` documentation,

@ [DataContractSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)

```
// You must apply a DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute
// to a class to have it serialized by the DataContractSerializer.
```

So, for WCF to work, you can get rid of `DataContract`s.

Comment: I need "Serializable" attribute to create a deepclone of the object and "DataContract" attribute so that I can use it in WCF service. Can you suggest me any ways to get rid of the "DataContract" attribute? Because as far as my knowledge goes it is not possible to transfer data in a WCF service using a class without "DataContract" attribute.

Comment: I had a discussion with my colleagues here and they are saying that if we keep just "Serializable" attribute then there is a performance hit and also that it will become as good as a web service. Also there is some problems with it that it does not property serialize some types. Also "DataMember" attribute on properties will not work with "Serializable" attribute on the class. The properties also needs to be marked as "Serializable". Is all this correct?

Answer (score 0):

@Samar The best way would be to use only DataContract attribute, as it internally makes the Serializable attribute come in to picture (by default).

Comment: I tried doing that but the thing is when i just keep the DataContract attribute I am not able to create a deep copy of the class. As you must be aware that creating a deep copy requires the class to be marked serializable and when I try to create the deep copy .net is saying that the class is not serialized even though I have marked the class as DataContract. Any reason y it is behaving in such a fashion?